# How to validate a model if model radio button is true in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have one radio button and two text boxes for user ID and password:

In Model

```
public bool IsUserExists {get;set;}

[Required]
public string UserID {get;set;}

[Required]
public string Password {get;set;}
```

Now, in Post Method, I want to validate Model conditionally in c# like if 'IsUserExists' is true.

```
  if(Model.IsValid){ // Model should validate if Radio button is true

 }
```

Please help on this.

Comment: Would need to see more of the controller-action code for this.

Comment: Your model will always validate, so not clear what your asking. Do you want the `IsUserExists` value to be `true` and if its not then `ModelState` showuld be invalid?

Answer (score 2):

Normally you could query the value of the `IsUserExists` model property on the server before performing validation:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
{
    if (model.IsUserExists)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           ...
        }
        else
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to perform real dynamic validation and avoid cluttering your controller with validation logic then you cannot use attributes because they are baked at compile-time. I would recommend you having a look at the [`FluentValidation`](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation) library which allows you to define dynamic complex validation logic and also has excellent [`integration with ASP.NET MVC`](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/h.-ASP.NET-MVC-5-integration).

Comment: Shouldn't OP check for valid model state first and then check for other condition?

Comment: No, because if `IsUserExists` is false on his view model, he doesn't want to perform any validation on the model - he doesn't want the hardcoded `[Required]` attributes to apply in this case. What he wants is to ensure that `UserID` and `Password` are populated **only if** the `IsUserExists` property is `true`.